# What is the expected performance of IEnumerable?

Tags: .net, performance, ienumerable

Properties are expected to perform similarly to fields, even though they are really functions.  What can be said about the expected performance of an arbitrary `IEnumerable`?

Is it fair to borrow the concept from properties and say that an `IEnumerable` should perform about the same as iterating an array or `List<T>`?

Or, is it okay for just about anything happen with each iteration: database access, web service call, time-consuming computation, etc.

Comment: Iteration is `O(n)` for some magical unspecified `C`. Of course the type-system *cannot* say "how long" it will take any more than it can in `for (var i in list) { doStuff(i); }`. These are the soft-fuzzy rules that should be specified in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from experience you can't really infer anything about the performance of an arbitrary `IEnumerable`. For example, it might be an `IQueryable` in disguise, hitting the database every time it is enumerated. Or it might be the result of `File.EnumerateLines`.

Sometimes it is important that the enumerable only be enumerated once.

**This is in contrast to a property.** If a property was to hit the database or read I file I'd consider this to be a code smell. For an `IEnumerable` it is just normal.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are too many examples for high-latency IEnumerable's. Occurs a lot in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there's no rule on how well an `IEnumerable<T>` should perform - only about how it should behave, which means it should loop through your collection.

If you need to access the database at the beginning of the iteration (like Entity Framework's `IQueryable<T>`), that's fine - if it needs to make a DB or file call per item, that's fine. The only important thing to me is that you can loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable has no properties, but the IEnumerable returns an IEnumerator, as you know.

If your object exposes a property that is of type IEnumerable, that is expected to return in constant time, but the **enumeration of that enumerator should probably have no expectations**.

Of course, **your situation may vary**.  For example, if you are binding some WPF control to that enumerable, your users will want it to return quickly.

Comment: I wouldn't think properties returning `IEnumerable` would have any "constant-time" expectations beyond the fact that `thing.property.action1(); thing.property.action2();` should not be hugely slower than `var foo = thing.property; foo.action1(); foo.action2();`.  Should `IEnumerable` properties have expectations beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

An `IEnumerable` of course can be used to access a database or crawl through a file, but if you expose such an `IEnumerable`, you should clearly document it doing so.

If it's not immediately clear that it's expensive, you should encapsulate it appropriately, and only expose an in-memory enumeration.

Comment: With a self-explanatory names of the class and the property of course, and XML comments describing exactly what they do.