# What is a good way to to indicate an IEnumerable is "slow" or "fast"?

Tags: .net, performance, ienumerable, iqueryable

The answer to [What is the expected performance of IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905297/what-is-the-expected-performance-of-ienumerable) says there's no way to know anyting about the performance of iterating an arbitrary IEnumerable.  Each iteration could hit a database or make a web serivce call; or it might just return the next item in an array/list.

Given that, is there a good way to indicate "this is fast"?  For example, with `T[]` or `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` I know that going from `T[i]` to `T[i+1]` will be quick.  (Of course, forcing the enumeration to return a list/array could create other performance concerns.  `List<T>` also exposes editable semantics.)

Conversely, would returning `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` be a good way to indicate "this is slow"?  Or maybe `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`?

Clients of `C` have no way of knowning that the `IEnumerable<T>`s will have dramatically different performance characteristics.

```
class C
{
   readonly T[] m_data;
   public IEnumerable<T> ThisWillIterateQuickly { get { return m_data; } }

   public IEnumeralbe<T> ThisWillIterateSlowly
   {
      get
      {
         T retval = ... an expensive database call ...;
         yield return retval;
      }
   }

   public IQueryable<T> IsThisBetterForSlow { get { return ThisWillIterateSlowly; } }
   public T[] IsThisAGoodWayForFast { get { return m_data; } }
 }
```

Comment: This may sound vague, but something is slow *only* if you think it's not *fast enough*.

Comment: There is no standard mechanism for advertising that. Maybe just: documentation?

Comment: Re the IQueryable... An array can be exposed as IQueryable - it says nothing about perf

Comment: Given that you seem to be implying that you have multiple data-structures containing the same data, and you need to differentiate between the fast structures and the slow ones... You might want to look at why you're doing that, and use the faster structures all the time?

Comment: Not something I'd recommend, but... if it's your own API then you could create a number of marker interfaces that just wrap `IEnumerable<>`, and then test for those markers. For example, `IReallyFastEnumerable<>`, `INotParticularlyFastEnumerable<>`, `ISnailsPaceEnumerable<>` etc.

Comment: @LukeH Of course that all falls apart when `IReallyFastEnumerable<>` causes a performance issue and you dismiss it initially because you assume it does what it says on the tin... cute idea though ;-)

Comment: @Dan The only downside with LukeH's comment is an enumerable may be fast over a small collection, but slow over a large collection. This would happen at runtime, you cannot change the implemented interfaces at runtime... so your convention breaks down. Unless you enforce the conditions under which something remains fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this some more, it seems the problem/question really centers on the behavior/performance of `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`.  Using *Visual Studio 2012*, I was able to create async versions of `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`:

```
public interface IAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDisposable
{
    Task<T> CurrentAsync { get; }
    Task<bool> MoveNextAsync();
    Task ResetAsync();
}

public interface IAsyncEnumerable<T>
{
    IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator();
}
```

A disadvantage to this approach is there isn't a lot of language support; the above won't work with `foreach`.  But, an extension method can ease the pain:

```
public static class EnumeratorExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                action(enumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        {
            while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
                action(await enumerator.CurrentAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why is `CurrentAsync` a `Task<T>`, surely the work is done in `MoveNextAsync`? So you could just have `T Current { get; }`

Comment: Fair enough, it doesn't seem intuitive to me, as I would expect a property getter to be fast. And why would a consumer move next if they didn't actually want the next item? In my opinion it makes more sense for `MoveNextAsync` to always do the work.

Answer (score 3):

> Conversely, would returning IQueryable instead of IEnumerable be a good way to indicate "this is slow"?

No, `IQueryable<T>` inherent from `IEnumerable<T>`... and the problem with `IEnumerable<T>T` is that it could be `IQueryable<T>` with a a huge side affect when iterating, like query a remote database or something like that.

Funny isn't it?

You probably should be asking about `IEnumerable<T>` V.S. `List<T>` which the second one definitely has the data in it, and doesn't need to get it from somewhere else.

Comment: @Dan. `IQueryable` usually hit the database but doesn't have to, it can get it's value from somewhere else, or hold it inside of it. But yes `IQueryable<T>` indicates there is something, a side effect better than `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to guarantee that iteration will not contain any surprises then I agree, expose a `T[]` - the enumerator for it cannot be overridden as you cannot inherit from arrays. Iteration is also side-effect free, the same cannot be said for `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, I would disagree that exposing an array ***expresses*** this message, which is more important (in my opinion). The performance of something can never really be expressed in code, unless you start naming stuff `CheapIteration` or `ExpensiveIteration`.

On the other side of the coin, with an array you simply move the performance problem of on-demand iteration to the point of populating the array. This is **guaranteed** to hit the performance problem fully as it will be a full iteration of whatever supplies the array contents. In an `IEnumerable<T>` if iteration stops, so does the performance problem - the fastest code is the code that doesn't run.

Comment: @Dan Forcing it to `T[]` involves a full iteration, which may be expensive. With `T[]` you also lose the deferred execution and force a run through the entire enumerable. Also, returning a `T[]` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` expresses **different intent**, people will have different expectations.

Comment: @Dan I would disagree that anything like this should be in the BCL. I wouldn't even want it in my own code personally. If I expose stuff to express how I want it to be consumed. Arrays express little, other than "here is a collection of stuff you can pretty much do what you want with". An `IEnumerable<T>` to me says "I'm to be iterated". Whether it is fast or slow or not shouldn't, in my opinion, be a concern to express in code. That said, it is an interesting topic. Returning an array would _implicitly_ express that iteration is fast, as nothing else can interject.

Comment: @Dan Can you tell that from code now or do you learn the framework, read documentation and profile to tell you that?  I have currently only ever gotten it from code because it was obvious, like Linq to SQL. That said, it you want to express this via code, then LukeH's comment is likely the best solution. The flip-side is, 30 seconds later when they run the app and it lags, they would learn it is slow and adapt. It then becomes a discussion about implementing a convention in your API that only saves the consumer a minute or so of development, but remains in your API for a lot longer.

Comment: @Dan But the UI would request an array, at which point, unless it was done off thread in preparation, the array will be populated which will still block the UI. Or like I said previously, you just move the expense elsewhere, at which point the UI again has to be aware of it to work accordingly.  The problem as I see it is, when do you stop trying to express the documentation of something in code? You've chosen to document the performance in code, why not the fact it touches the database or a network, for example.

Comment: If the UI doesn't want to risk it, then by default it should thread the work. What if it is given an array if a million items? There are way too many potential points at which the convention breaks or otherwise doesn't fully address the problem. I'd leave it up to the consumer, your only responsibility would be to make the array load or enumerable iteration as optimised as you can.

Comment: To clarify: by "expose an T[]", do you mean "expose an internal T[]", or "have a function that returns a new T[]", or "have a member which accepts a T[] as a ref parameter and either populates it or generates a suitably-sized instance, as needed, and returns the number of items used", or what?  The third semantics would seem in many cases to be the most efficient, and could easily be wrapped by a method providing the second.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use properties for returning 'quick' enumerations and methods for 'slow'.

Your problem is an argument for using asynchronous approach and design as much as possible. Then it really doesn't matter how long the enumeration takes, as the UI is responsive and the user happy ;-)